# How to upload a file on internet with VBA?

Tags: html, vba, filedialog

I have this HTML code and I have in my VBA code, the path of the file, but I have no idea how to upload this file.

```
<td>
                    <div style="display:none;"><input type="file" name="ctl00$ctl00$cphc$corpo$ucAndamento$fuDocumento" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphc_corpo_ucAndamento_fuDocumento" /></div>
                    <div id="divControles"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ctl00$cphc$corpo$ucAndamento$hdnDocumentos" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphc_corpo_ucAndamento_hdnDocumentos" />
                </td>
```

And the only thing that I've tried was:

```
IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_cphc_corpo_ucAndamento_fuDocumento").click
```

But It open a FileDialog, that do nothing.